# Ethereum and bullying and possible coersion to delete by third parties

Tags: ether, nodes, explorers, legal

I am new to Ethereum.

I want to use Ethereum to allow the voice of a number of oppressed groups I have knowledge of to be:

- voiced
- spread
- accessible from anywhere and unhidden
- anonymously contributed
- *made permanent and forever undeletable*

I would like to know, given the network technology used to implement Ethereum, if a bullying our financially influential party in the future ordeals that all information be deleted, can they force Ethereum programmers to change the technology so that some stuff is actually permanently deleted? Are there legally opposing constraints?

Answer (score 2):

> can they force Ethereum programmers to change the technology so that some stuff is actually permanently deleted?

Adding "stuff" to the Ethereum blockchain is in the hands of miners and is not controlled by a single authority (e.g. Ethereum programmers). It can't be deleted by anyone. Once the information is on the blockchain, it's there forever. However, if something drastic like the DAO attack happens, there might be a [fork](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/) which can make the information valid/invalid.

**EDIT:** Answers to reflect your comments

> Is this theoretically possible?

Yes. But remember all it(Ethereum Network) requires is a single node which has the complete blockchain data to be up and running.

> how do I ensure miners on other computers duplicate the information so that it is not lost?

When an Ethereum client is installed on a machine, the blockchain data automatically gets downloaded when an instance is started. So, every miner in the Ethereum Network has the complete blockchain data.

To get answers to your other questions, I suggest you read a bit about mining and how the blockchain works.

Comment: But can't a powerful organization poss on the government's of every country to confiscate all computers having any data that it does not have an interest in being accessible on the various Ethereum blockchains? Is this theoretically possible? This would force computer owners to remove the Ethereum software on their computers to avoid becoming victims of government corruption. Is it not so?

Comment: Also, if I have Ethereum running on my computer, and add the information I want to the blockchain, then how do I ensure miners on other computers duplicate the information so that it is not lost? Also, how do opposed miners convince other miners to not add the information from my computer to their blockchains? Also, how does a miner decide what to add to the blockchain and why, if there are for duplicating this data across the network? Thanks.