# What is meant by 'consensus breaking changes'?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

Reading this Blockstack paper : https://blockstack.org/blockstack.pdf it states :

```
With Blockstack,
we extend the single state machine model of
blockchains to allow for arbitrary state machines without
requiring consensus breaking changes in the underlying
blockchain.
```

What is meant by 'consensus breaking changes' ? Is it related to once 51% consensus has been achieved that something can break ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consensus breaking change is one that requires **everyone** to upgrade their software client so that consensus is maintained.  For example: updating the block size in Bitcoin.  If larger blocks are implemented in Bitcoin, **everyone** must update their client because old software basically cannot process larger blocks.  Such changes are [hardforks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/what-is-a-hardfork) and those who do not update their software cannot be synchronized with the blockchain.